# why am i seeing "error while loading route" with ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

ember rc1, ember-data rev 12.  all my other routes load correctly, unsure why i'm seeing this error. it happens when i try to access the show route i.e. /files/groups/5.  the index route renders fine.

i've pasted the stack trace below but it's not very informative.  is there something basically wrong i'm doing here?

my routes/controllers are set up as follows:

```
this.resource('files', { path : '/files' }, function() {      
  this.resource('groups', { path : '/groups' }, function() {      
    this.route('show', { path : '/:asset_link_group_id' });      
  });
});

AssetLinksApp.GroupsShowController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  content : Ember.A(),
  assetLinkGroup : null
});

AssetLinksApp.GroupsShowRoute = AssetLinksApp.AuthRequiredRoute.extend({
  setupController : function(controller,model) {    
  controller.set('content',model.get('asset_links'));
  controller.set('assetLinkGroup',model);
  },
  model : function(params) {    
    return AssetLinksApp.AssetLinkGroup.find(params.asset_link_group_id);
  }
});
```

the stack trace:

> Error while loading route: TypeError {} exchange_vendor.js:12078
>
> (anonymous function) exchange_vendor.js:12078
>   Ember.Router.reopenClass.defaultFailureHandler.setup
>   exchange_vendor.js:35011 failure exchange_vendor.js:34448
>   objects.concat.context exchange_vendor.js:34497 invokeCallback
>   exchange_vendor.js:17846 Promise.then exchange_vendor.js:17893
>   EventTarget.trigger exchange_vendor.js:17822 results
>   exchange_vendor.js:17924 RunLoop._prev exchange_vendor.js:15911
>   Ember.handleErrors exchange_vendor.js:12140 invoke
>   exchange_vendor.js:15909 iter exchange_vendor.js:15981 RunLoop.flush
>   exchange_vendor.js:16035 RunLoop.end exchange_vendor.js:15940 tryable
>   exchange_vendor.js:16143 Ember.tryFinally exchange_vendor.js:12831
>   Ember.run.end exchange_vendor.js:16146 Ember.tryFinally
>   exchange_vendor.js:12833 Ember.run exchange_vendor.js:16102
>   Ember.HashLocation.Ember.Object.extend.onUpdateURL
>   exchange_vendor.js:36690 jQuery.event.dispatch exchange_vendor.js:3144
>   jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle

Comment: it seems to be something wrong with the model: function() in GroupsShowRoute.  if i return a null model, i don't see the error.  i realize that that model() function is redundant as the router provides that implementation by default.

Comment: but i don't see what's wrong with that find() call.. if i try it in the console, it runs successfully and provides a valid Model instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The model returns a single record.  However you have defined an `ArrayController`.

Ember.js automatically places the model in the controller's content property, which will cause an error since it will be putting a single record in an array controller.

Even though you overrode the `setupController`, before it fires, Ember.js will place the model in the controller anyway.  There's currently no way of stopping that.

---

#### Update 3-June-2014 (Ember > 1.0) :

If you now override `setupController` Ember no longer sets the `model` property.

---

The only solution I can think of is to add a resource to your routes:

```
this.resource('files', { path : '/files' }, function() {      
  this.resource('groups', { path : '/groups' }, function() {      
    this.resource('group', { path : '/:asset_link_group_id' }, function() {
      this.route('index');
    });      
   });
});
```

This means that you have an object controller (`GroupController`) containing the group,
and an array controller (`GroupIndexController`) containing the asset links array.

```
AssetLinksApp.GroupIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  assetLinkGroup : null
});

AssetLinksApp.GroupIndexRoute = AssetLinksApp.AuthRequiredRoute.extend({
  setupController : function(controller,model) {    
    controller.set('content',model);
    controller.set('assetLinkGroup', this.modelFor('group'));
  },
  model : function(params) {    
    return this.modelFor('group').get('asset_links');
  }
});
```

Now your template should be named `group/index` instead of `groups/show`.  As for `group` template, it can be an empty template containing `{{outlet}}`.

Most important thing to note from this is:  If your controller is an object controller, you **have** to return an object from the model hook, and if your controller is an array controller, then you **have** to return an array from the model hook.

The bright side is, this pushes you to follow a certain design that I and probably the core team think is better.

Comment: thank you very much for such a detailed response.  now i understand that i've not structured my app very well.  i will be rebuilding the structure today.

Comment: a followup question regarding app structure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660598/in-ember-how-are-views-names-determined-with-respect-to-the-router