# in ember how are view's names determined with respect to the router?

Tags: ember.js

ember rc1.  i don't understand how views are automatically instantiated by naming convention wrt their routes.

i have the following resource defined:

```
  this.resource('groups', { path : '/groups' }, function() {
      this.resource('received', { path : '/received' }, function() {            
        this.route('show', { path : '/:asset_link_group_id' });
  });
```

when the router instantiates the view for groups/received/index it looks for a view named ReceivedIndexView.  why not GroupsReceivedIndexView ?

the same goes for controllers - it looks for ReceivedIndexController, not GroupsReceivedIndexController. why?

Answer (score 0):

"Routes nested under a resource take the name of the resource plus their name as their route name", from http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

My understanding of the setup is that a route is looked at and then it's parent resource in order to automatically derive the patching.  In this way /resource1/sameresourcename/new and /resource2/sameresourcename/new will actually cause problems because it doesn't use the full "tree" to generate these paths/names.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time researching this as i was having problems understanding the hows and whys of the naming conventions. This is the most informative site I have found in regards to which pieces of the route/resources are picked to create the view/controller/resource name.

From Peter "We intentionally only nest one level deep. The correct solution is what @jamesarosen suggested."

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2086